# Why is a row in my DataGridView being automatically selected when updating the data source?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a DataTable that is acting as the data source for a DataGridView

```
private readonly DataTable _processTable = new DataTable();

ProcessDataGrid.DataSource = _processTable;
```

I have a method that populates this DataTable (and in doing so populates the DataGridView)

```
private void PopulateDataTable()
{
    var processes = Process.GetProcesses();

    foreach(var process in processes)
    {
        _processTable.Rows.Add(process.ProcessName);
    }
}
```

I also have a button, that when pressed calls `PopulateDataTable`

```
private void RefreshButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    _processTable.Rows.Clear();

    // Refresh the process list

    PopulateDataTable();
}
```

When `RefreshButton` is clicked, the data source is cleared and updates correctly, however, it selects a row around half way into the list and scrolls to that value in the DataGridView.

I want to prevent this from occurring, so that when the button is clicked, the data source updates like it is currently doing, however, the no row in automatically scrolled to in the DataGridView (the user's current position relative to the scrollbar doesn't change.)

How could I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note down the previously selected row index before you refresh the `DataTable`. Then select the same row again after refreshing it.

**Hint:** `dataGridViewControl.CurrentRow` is a read-only property, therefore use `dataGridViewControl.CurrentCell` for both reading and setting the current row. Make sure you implement a check to see whether `CurentCell` property is `null` or not and also the row index that you are about to select is NOT beyond the bounds.